# Python Web Scraping HTTP 400

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm doing a web scrape with Python (using the Scrapy framework). The scrape works successfully until it gets about an hour into the process and then every request comes back with a HTTP400 error code.

Is this just likely to be a IP based rate limiter or scrape detection tool? Any advice on how I might investigate the root cause further?

Comment: Does an error message come with the 400 error code?

Comment: Is it at 3600 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the request rate. try with some [download_delay](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html#download-delay). if you are able to request more pages before 400 error, then you can adjust download_delay and get full web content. Some website give info about download_delay in their robots.txt file

Answer (score 0):

It could be a rate limiter.

However a 400 error generally means that the client request was malformed and therefore rejected by the server.

You should start investigating this first. When your requests start failing, exit your program and immediately start it again. If it starts working, you know that you aren't being rate-limited and that there is in fact something wrong with how your requests are formed later on.

Comment: It does work if I cancel and start again, but I just can't see how the requests would be changing part way through the script. Is there anything I can do to inspect the request?